# Sed Delete first line of every file that ends has .jsx extension

Tags: linux, shell, sed

So in React 0.12 having `/** @jsx React.DOM */` at the top of all jsx files is no longer necessary. A library that I'm using actually throws an error when it sees the `/** @jsx React.DOM */` line that exists at the top of every jsx file.

So I wanted to know if there was a quick way using sed to remove this line from every file within a directory.

Should I just remove line 1, or is there a way for me to pattern match, and verify that it's at the top? Also how would one recursively remove it from all files within a directory, and it's subdirectories?

Thank you!

Comment: How to in-file replace a match and delete a line can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed

How to recursively traverse directories is here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897264/bash-writing-a-script-to-recursively-travel-a-directory-of-n-levels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's simple with the help of `find`. The following command lines the first line of all **.jsx*  files:

```
find /path/to/files -name '*.jsx' -exec sed -i '1d' {} \;
```

This command removes lines containing that certain comment:

```
find /path/to/files -name '*.jsx' -exec sed -i '/^\/\*\* @jsx React\.DOM \*\/$/d' {} \;
```

Make a backup of your files before issuing that commands since they modify the files in place. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: To be 100% safe you should really escape the `*`s and the `.` in the regexp - `/\/\*\* @jsx React\.DOM \*\//` and it MAY even be appropriate to anchor it `/^\/\*\* @jsx React\.DOM \*\/$/` if that's the whole line.

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed! You are right. I had in mind that `*` when used as a quantifier in `sed`, without passing `-r`, needs to get escaped. I should blame *you* because you showed me to use more `awk` and less `sed`. :) You see, my knowledge about `sed` get's rusty already!